# How to create a URL with no ".html" to download a file?

Tags: url, download

I want to create a handful of URL's on my server that allow you to download a file from a "direct link" but not a direct link such as `www.website.com/file-for-download.exe` I'd like it to just be  `www.website.com/download` and then it would start downloading the `.exe`

So I would essentially have:

`www.website.com/download`

`www.website.com/download2`

`www.website.com/download3`

Each with it's own file that will give you the option to download when you visit the link.

**How can I create a URL that doesn't end with ".html" but starts a download link?**

Comment: A couple of different ways, I imagine.  If you have a web application then you can use whatever URL scheme it can use and write code to return the stream of the file.  You could re-write the URLs in the web server and/or directory configuration to direct to the file for specific URLs.  Since we don't know anything about your setup we can't really be more specific.  But at a general level there's no rule that says a URL must contain a file name.  HTTP has no concept of "files".  Your server can respond with any headers/content you like for any request.

Comment: I have files uploaded via FileZilla. And my webpages in the root directory

Comment: FileZilla has, in every way, absolutely nothing to do with the question you're asking.

Comment: @David I'm wondering if there is someway to upload my downloadable file to FileZilla along with a html file that can allow users to download said file. Just that I don't want the link to go to an actual `.html` link. just one that downloads the file directly but not using the file name itself, e.g. `download-1.exe`

Comment: What sort of webserver is this?

Comment: This wouldn't be a function of FileZilla, it would be a function of the web server and/or web application.  For example, if you're using Apache or something similar with `.htaccess` files then the answer below should work.

Comment: @JonHanna I'm sorry I don't know. I just manage the files that go onto FileZilla. I don't know how to find out what sort of web server it is.

Comment: What headers do you get when you look at a file in your browser? Examine the headers with the developer tools in firefox or chrome etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your `.htaccess` file to do this.

```
RewriteRule ^download$ "/file.exe" [P]
```

Then when you type `http://example.com/download` you'll download the file called `file.exe`

Comment: This worked, apart from I had to change `[P]` to `[R]`.. found that out after a little searching, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: is there anyway to go deeper with this method? so let's say `http://example.com/download/one/two` then download the file? I tried extending `^download/$` to `^download/one/two$` but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

function onTelegramAuth(user) {
    alert('Logged in as ' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + ' (' + user.id + (user.username ? ', @' + user.username : '') + ')');
  }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).